# Android: Exception when converting a String into a JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

I get the following Error when I try to convert a JSON String into a JSONObject.

> Value **48.466667|9.883333** at location of type java.lang.String
>   cannot be converted to JSONObject

The String is valid JSON, I tested it with http://jsonlint.com/

Example:
{"name":"An der Decke","location":"**48.412583|10.0385**","type":"Virtual","size":null,"status":"Available","difficulty":1,"rating":null,"terrain":1}

The code that produces the exception looks like that:

```
jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
jsonArray = new JSONArray();
Iterator<String> iter = jsonObject.keys();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = iter.next();
    try {
        JSONObject value = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get(key);   <---- Exception
        jsonArray.put(value);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Something went wrong!
    }
}
```

Is the pipe | symbol not a valid character in Java JSON?

EDIT:

The thing is, it works fine if the JSON String doesn't include the **"location":"48.412583|10.0385"** part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is just to get a `JSONArray` of all your JSON string values, there's a much simpler way to do it.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.toJSONArray(jsonObject.names());

System.out.println(jsonArray); // prints:
// [1,"Available","48.412583|10.0385","An der Decke",1,null,"Virtual",null]
```

With that aside, you were wrong to assume that every value encapsulated within JSON would be a JSON object itself. In fact, in your case none of them are. The correct types of all the values in your JSON are

```
// String
System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("name")); // An der Decke
System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("location")); // 48.412583|10.0385
System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("type")); // Virtual
System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("status")); // Available

// Null
System.out.println(jsonObject.isNull("size")); // true
System.out.println(jsonObject.isNull("rating")); // true

// Integer
System.out.println(jsonObject.getInt("terrain")); // 1
System.out.println(jsonObject.getInt("difficulty")); // 1
```

On the other hand, if your `name` was an embedded JSON object consisting of first, middle and last names, your JSON string (ignoring the rest of the keys for brevity) would have looked like

```
{"name": {"fname" : "An", "mname" : "der", "lname" : "Decke"}}
```

Now, we can put `getJSONObject()` to use because we really do have an embedded JSON object.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{\"name\":
                     {\"fname\" : \"An\", \"mname\" : \"der\", \"lname\" : \"Decke\"}}");

// get embedded "name" JSONObject
JSONObject name = jsonObj.getJSONObject("name");

System.out.println(name.getString("fname") + " "
                 + name.getString("mname") + " "
                 + name.getString("lname")); // An der Decke
```

Comment: Ok, that means I have to treat each item dependent of it's type...thx

Comment: @user2708728, Yes. I've added an example on when to use `getJSONObject()` as well.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to misunderstand how the `org.json` library works.

As explained on the [JSON homepage](http://www.json.org/), a JSON value can be a string, number, object, array, true/false or null. The library maps these value types to `String`, `Number` subclasses, `JSONArray`, `JSONObject`, `Boolean` or `null`.

**Not everything in that library is a `JSONObject`.** In fact, a `JSONObject` is *specifically* used to represent a name/value pair object. `JSONObject.get()` can potentially return *any* of the aforementioned value types, that's why it needs to fall back to the greatest common denominator type: `Object` (and *not* `JSONObject`). Thus, casting everything to a `JSONObject` won't work.

It's *your responsibility* to ensure that you're casting to the correct type using your knowledge of the incoming data structure. This seems to be a problem in your case: your JSON string contains strings (for `name`, `location`, `type` and `status`), integers (for `difficulty` and `terrain`) and nulls (for `size`). What *exactly* are you trying to do with these?

Answer (score 0):

The [`get()`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#get%28java.lang.String%29) method of `JSONObject` returns a result of type `Object`. In this case, it seems it is a `String`. It's as if you were doing

```
JSONObject value = (JSONObject) new String("asdasdsa");
```

which obviously makes no sense as they are incompatible types.

Instead, retrieve the value, create a `JSONObject` from it and add it to the `JSONArray`.